# What are some http mining pools out there?

Tags: stratum, http

The open source FPGA miner with source available at https://github.com/progranism/Open-Source-FPGA-Bitcoin-Miner does not support stratum, so in order to test it, I need an http pool. Are there any left?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use getblocktemplate. If you do an http POST to http://gbt.mining.eligius.st:9337 with a body of:

```
{"id": 0, "method": "getblocktemplate", "params": [{"capabilities": ["coinbasetxn", "workid", "coinbase/append"]}]}
```

You should get a transactions to process. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate for more information.

I can't find many other sites that support GBT but there is a list of compatible pools in the above link as well.

Comment: Looking at the source code linked to by the question, it seems that that project requires the old "getwork" RPC, which was deprecated and removed years ago.

Comment: Good point. The source code also hasn't been updated for 4-5 years. Another possibility would be to revert to bitcoin v0.9.5 which is the last version prior to removal of "getwork" and get something going. Otherwise, the code would need to be upgraded.